# External Display Issues Lenovo W530 Ubuntu 12.10, VGA not recognized

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, lenovo

I am running a Lenovo W530 with Ubuntu 12.10. I have tried every solution I could find for this issue but to no avail.

Ubuntu will not recognize that I have a VGA monitor connected to the laptop. I realize that the VGA connector goes through the NVIDIA driver.

What I have tried(would provide more links but I need my rep needs to be greater than 10 to post more than two):

- [The Steps Lined out by Jim](http://prjorgensen.com/2012/10/21/ubuntu-on-thinkpad-t430s-and-w530/)
- [What applied to my system from Sagark](http://sagark.org/optimal-ubuntu-graphics-setup-for-thinkpads/)
- Trying to force the driver to be on with bbswitch
- changing the BIOS so that it would run in Discrete (it will boot but I get horrible resolution and still no external display...also seems that compwiz does not work well while in this mode
- Went through a couple of additional threads about getting a VIRTUAL display. However,  every time I try to install the patch that was hacked for the intel driver for the virtual display capabilities, my intel display crashes and I have to revert.
- Virtualization is enabled for my Intel display in the BIOS

I have hit a wall. I have also read through about 10 different questions on here and none have helped. Should I completely scrap the Nvidia drivers on my machine and run only with bumblebee? Has there been any success with that?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Kernel:  3.5.0-26-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm running a lenovo w530 with ubuntu 12.10 
i faced the same issue this week ... i did the following:
http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/
except instead of nvidia-current-updates i use nvidia-current (but there shouldn't be a difference)

then i switched to discrete mode and voila your external display should work (kernel 3.5.0-27.46-generic)

kr raphael

Comment: This essentially WORKED!!! However, due to my previous experiments, I needed to remove bumblebee, bbswitch, purge my Nvidia-current, get it again, reboot with discrete and it worked. I was a bit nervous at first because it was booting into low res but then that rare moment of computer magic happened and it worked. Thank you sir. I would upvote but I do not have the rep yet on this sub stack. Answer: ACCEPTED

Comment: This answer combined with the comment by @bwtrent worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Does this allow you to display to an external monitor *and* the Thinkpad's display?

Comment: @Malcolm Yes I am able to use 2 external monitors (DVI from docking station) and the Thinkpad display. I am running a Thinkpad W530.

Comment: @OSE thanks for letting me know. I'm running 13.04. I haven't been able to get my thinkpad display to work with discrete mode enabled in bios. I'll have to poke around on the weekend or something to get this all to work. It's good to know that it at least works for you (means it might work for me!).

Comment: @Malcolm I'm running my w530 right now with 13.04 and it works out of box with external monitor & thinkpad monitor, (no nvidia driver, just the standard nouveau driver installed, which is there when i install ubuntu) - when I want to use an external monitor I switch do discrete graphics mode & optimus disabled - when I'm using just the thinkpad monitor or I run win8 with external monitor I switch back to nvidia optimus & optimus enabled (I even switch back when just using ubuntu because I can't control the backlight in discrete mode :( ..)

Comment: @RaphaelStary thanks for letting me know! You switch this in bios, right? If you're using discrete mode, are you able to just use the thinkpad display? It's quite unfortunate that NVidia's optimus is so convoluted that true Linux support for it doesn't work :(